# Will switching GPU device affect the gradient in PyTorch back propagation?

Tags: pytorch, gpu, cpu, gradient-descent, backpropagation

I use the Pytorch. In the computation, I move some data and operators A in the GPU. In the middle step, I move the data and operators B to CPU and continue the forward.

My question is that:

My operator B is very memory-consuming that cannot be used in GPU. Will this affect (some parts compute in GPU and the others are computed in CPU) the backpropagation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pytorch keeps track of the location of tensors. If you use `.cpu()` or `.to('cpu')` pytorch's native commands you should be okay.

See, e.g., [this model parallel](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/model_parallel_tutorial.html) tutorial - the computation is split between two *different* GPU devices.

Answer (score 1):

If your model fits into the GPU memory, you might let PyTorch do the parallel distribution for you within the `DataParallel` (one process multiple threads) or `DistributedDataParallel` (multiple processes multiple threads, single or multiple nodes) frameworks.

Code below checks if you have a gpu device `torch.cuda.device_count() > 1` and sets the `DataParallel` mode `model = nn.DataParallel(model)`

```
model = Model(input_size, output_size)
if torch.cuda.device_count() > 1:
  print("Let's use", torch.cuda.device_count(), "GPUs!")
  # dim = 0 [30, xxx] -> [10, ...], [10, ...], [10, ...] on 3 GPUs
  model = nn.DataParallel(model)

model.to(device)
```

`DataParallel` replicates the same model to all GPUs, where each GPU consumes a different partition of the input data, it can significantly accelerate the training process, but it does not work for some use cases where the model is too large to fit into a single GPU.

To solve this problem, you might resort to a `model parallel` approach, which splits a single model onto different GPUs, rather than replicating the entire model on each GPU.

(e.g. a model m contains 10 layers: when using DataParallel, each GPU
will have a replica of each of these 10 layers, whereas when using
model parallel on two GPUs, each GPU could host 5 layers)

An example where `.to('cuda:0')` indicates where the layer should be positioned.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim


class ToyModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ToyModel, self).__init__()
        self.net1 = torch.nn.Linear(10, 10).to('cuda:0')
        self.relu = torch.nn.ReLU()
        self.net2 = torch.nn.Linear(10, 5).to('cuda:1')

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.relu(self.net1(x.to('cuda:0')))
        return self.net2(x.to('cuda:1'))
```

`backward()` then automatically takes location into consideration.

```
model = ToyModel()
loss_fn = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

optimizer.zero_grad()
outputs = model(torch.randn(20, 10))
labels = torch.randn(20, 5).to('cuda:1')
loss_fn(outputs, labels).backward()
optimizer.step()
```

https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/model_parallel_tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

This snippet suggests that the gradient is preserved when computation goes through different devices.

```
def change_device():
    import torch.nn as nn
    a = torch.rand((4, 32))
    m1 = nn.Linear(32, 32)
    cpu = m1(a)
    gpu = cpu.to(0)
    m2 = nn.Linear(32, 32).to(0)
    out = m2(gpu)
    loss = out.sum()
    loss.backward()
    print(m1.weight.grad)
    # works like magic
    """
    tensor([[ 0.7746,  1.0342,  0.8706,  ...,  1.0993,  0.7975,  0.3915],
        [-0.5369, -0.7169, -0.6034,  ..., -0.7619, -0.5527, -0.2713],
        [ 0.3607,  0.4815,  0.4053,  ...,  0.5118,  0.3713,  0.1823],
        ...,
        [ 1.1200,  1.4955,  1.2588,  ...,  1.5895,  1.1531,  0.5660],
        [-0.1582, -0.2112, -0.1778,  ..., -0.2245, -0.1629, -0.0799],
        [-0.4531, -0.6050, -0.5092,  ..., -0.6430, -0.4665, -0.2290]])
    """
```

Modifying this snippet, the gradient is preserved when tensor moves from gpu to cpu as well.